# Giving stocks as a gift to offset losses

Tags: united-states, stocks, capital-loss

Suppose I have accumulated some stock exchange losses in the past. My parents gift me some stocks. Do I get to realize capital gains when I sell those stocks? If my parents bought the stock for $100 and now it's worth $200 and my past losses are $500, does that mean that I'll have to pay no taxes on the sale (because they are offset by my old losses)?

Comment: Is this for the US? Tax and gift laws vary by country.

Comment: Tip: Tax questions should always have a country tag included.

Comment: Sure, it's Uzbekistan. I mean USA. (Although if you knew something about Uzbek tax law, that'd be quite impressive.)

Comment: You said past losses. When did you sell those shares: 2020? 2021? When was the gift?

Comment: The losses are in the past the gift is in the future. The question is regarding the feasibility of the scheme.